# Connection to api.openweathermap.org timed out error?

Tags: python, api, openweathermap

I wrote this code to get weather update in specified city:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import pyowm
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

win=tk.Tk()


#frame_for_showing_weather.
weather_frame=Frame(win,bg='black',width='300',height='300')
weather_frame.place(x=0,y=0)


weath=Label(weather_frame,font=('Agency',100),fg='white',bg='black')
weath.place(x=10,y=10)

temp1=''
owm=pyowm.OWM('a1bdf2e4609febbedaf0fcc823e3d527')

def obs():
    global temp1
    observation = owm.weather_at_place('Barisal,BD')
    w=observation.get_weather()
    temp2=w.get_temperature('celsius')
    if(temp2!=temp1):
        temp1=temp2['temp']
        weath.config(text=str(int(temp1))+chr(176))        
    weath.after(60000,obs)
obs()


win.mainloop()
```

But after sometime, this big error occured in my shell:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 79, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 69, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1106, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 196, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 176, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.timeout))
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x041A0CB0>, 'Connection to api.openweathermap.org timed out. (connect timeout=2)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.openweathermap.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /data/2.5/weather?APPID=a1bdf2e4609febbedaf0fcc823e3d527&lang=en&q=Barisal%2CBD (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x041A0CB0>, 'Connection to api.openweathermap.org timed out. (connect timeout=2)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\http_client.py", line 24, in get_json
    timeout=self.timeout, verify=self.verify_ssl_certs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 501, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.openweathermap.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /data/2.5/weather?APPID=a1bdf2e4609febbedaf0fcc823e3d527&lang=en&q=Barisal%2CBD (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x041A0CB0>, 'Connection to api.openweathermap.org timed out. (connect timeout=2)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 596, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\James Bond\Desktop\test.py", line 23, in obs
    observation = owm.weather_at_place('Barisal,BD')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyowm\webapi25\owm25.py", line 210, in weather_at_place
    _, json_data = self._wapi.cacheable_get_json(uri, params=params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\http_client.py", line 44, in cacheable_get_json
    status_code, data = self.get_json(uri, params=params, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\http_client.py", line 28, in get_json
    raise api_call_error.APIInvalidSSLCertificateError(str(e))
pyowm.exceptions.api_call_error.APIInvalidSSLCertificateError: Exception in calling OWM web API.

Reason: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.openweathermap.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /data/2.5/weather?APPID=a1bdf2e4609febbedaf0fcc823e3d527&lang=en&q=Barisal%2CBD (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x041A0CB0>, 'Connection to api.openweathermap.org timed out. (connect timeout=2)'))

Caused by: None
```

please someone tell me why this error occurred and how can fix it!

Comment: Timeout errors occur all the time with sockets and the internet. You should use try..except around those calls and learn to report and recover from those exceptions.  Also, does this line `owm=pyowm.OWM('a1bdf2e4609febbedaf0fcc823e3d527')` have a personal key for openweathermap.org?  You shouldn't post your keys in questions unless there is no exposure for you in doing so.

Comment: I am new at python. and I use this code for my college project.please give  me suggestion how can i use try,except  around this calls for this error.@RufusVS

Comment: Upon rereading your posting, it isn't clear if it starts working, but then times out, or if it didn't even get its first update.  You can try running the lines of code one by one in the Python shell to make sure each line returns what you expect.

Comment: @RufusVS Its starts working and it getting update after 1 minute.but if network disconnect or slow network this big error occure.and I want if my pc network reconnect this will start working automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply ignore socket timeouts, you might be able 
to rewrite your obs function to trap that exception, like this:

```
from socket import timeout

def obs():
    global temp1
    try:
        observation = owm.weather_at_place('Barisal,BD')
        w=observation.get_weather()
        temp2=w.get_temperature('celsius')
        if(temp2!=temp1):
            temp1=temp2['temp']
            weath.config(text=str(int(temp1))+chr(176))
    except timeout as e:
        print "socket timeout."
        pass
    weath.after(60000,obs)
```

That may be all you need.

I don't knowing how OWM works, you might have to close it and re-open it to get fresh socket.  You can do that in the except block. Add

```
global owm
```

in your function and in the except block, repeat the line:

```
owm=pyowm.OWM('a1bdf2e4609febbedaf0fcc823e3d527')
```

Which will create a new OWM object, presumably closing out the old one and opening the new one.